# No comma's in decimal

Tags: javascript

```
const numberWithCommas = (x) => {
 return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

I have this function in which if a number is sent like `1223.00001` It will return like `1,223.00,001` but I would like to get 1,223.00001 ! I would like to get decimals without commas! This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript) is giving me different answer !

Comment: Note: When I run your function on `1223.00001`, I get `1,223.00,001` instead of `1,223.00,00,1` (which you use in your question). Ensure that your inputs and outputs are correct in your question.

Comment: what does `1223.00001.toLocaleString('en', {maximumFractionDigits:20})` do? probably what you want :p

Comment: *"This question is giving me different answer !"* Have you actually looked at the bottom of the accepted answer? Or the second and third highest voted answers?

Answer (score 0):

You may add a positive lookahead to your regex which asserts that a decimal point follows.  This guarantees that the replacement only happens to the whole number component.

```js
x = "1223.00001";
x = x.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))(?=.*\.)/g, ",");
console.log(x);
```

One rather brute force option would be to just apply your current regex to the whole number side of the input.  Then, concatenate that replaced result with the decimal portion.

```js
x = "1223.00001";
top = x.replace(/\..*$/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
bottom = x.replace(/^.*\./, "");
console.log(top + "." + bottom);
```